# High CPU utilization for high specs server using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I have written code in python that processes images and stores results in an Oracle Database. It first pulls the IDs of the images, and using the multiprocessing library in Python, it splits this array to the spawned processes. Each image is independent from the rest and can be processed separately.

I am currently running this code on a server with 32 processors and have only created two processes to run in parallel. I have found that the CPU utilization has spiked up to 70%. Running a single process sets it to around 40%.

Is there an explanation for CPU utilization with this library?

Code snippet:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
num_of_processes = 2
img_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
process_list = []

split_img_lst = np.array_split(img_list, num_of_processes)

for i in range(num_of_processes):
    flat_list = [item for sublist in split_img_lst[i] for item in sublist]
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = process_imgs, args = (flat_list, i))
    process_list.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in process_list:
    p.join()
```

I expected that for one process the utilization would be a little about 1/32 of the CPU capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Percent CPU utilization for a process is the percent of times this process runs on a particular core. So if %cpu for a process is 40% what this means exactly is that this process runs 40% of times on this core.

%CPU does not really mean that the core itself is 40% utilized, as CPU time is in the form of clock cycles so either a process will the clock cycles or it won't, so it is a atomic operation.

Load average on the system gives you a better how much your actual cores are utilized, so for a 32 core machine a load average < 32 means that not all the cores are being used at this point and there are no processes waiting.

Now coming to multiprocessing, when you launch the program with a single process you are occupying the overall CPU on the system 40% of times(note there are other processes running on the system which collectively runs 60% of times). However when you increase the number of process you are increasing the percentage of how many times your program would run on the CPU.

So yes this is the expected behavior, and it is not just with python multiprocessing, this is the general behavior of multiprocessing in computer science.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation on percentage CPU utilization. Is it safe to push CPU utilization to the maximum, if this is a dedicated server for the task?

How do you find load avg on a Windows Machine?

Comment: I would say it is a good idea to push overall cpu utilization to let's say 70%. On windows machines I guess you would have to go to Task Manager to check the CPU stats.

Comment: The Task Manager shows "70% CPU Usage" with just 3 processes.

Comment: It is fine I guess as there will be other processes also running on the machine and since you are actually doing lot of CPU intensive stuff with numpy and image processing I would expect CPU utilization to spike

Comment: I have traced down the utilization to keras. The line ```model.predict(img)``` is what spikes up the utilization.

Comment: Of course this is quite cpu intensive work as I already pointed out in my previous comment. In 9 cases out of 10 you would use multiprocessing for cpu intensive tasks and this will definitely spike up the cpu usage.